# Text Analytics, DocumentTermMatrix in R translated into Python

Tags: python, r, text, text-processing

I have the following code in R and looking for the equivalent in Python. What I want to do is take the words from a text, clean them up (remove punctuation, lower, strip white space, etc.) and create variables out of them in a matrix format that can be used in a predictive model.

```
text<- c("amazing flight",
         "got there early",
         "great prices on flights??")
mydata_1<- data.frame(text)

library(tm)
corpus<- Corpus(DataframeSource(mydata_1))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus<- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)

dtm_1<- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
final_output<- as.matrix(dtm_1)
```

The output looks like this below where the words "amazing", "early", etc. are now binary input variables that I can use in a model:

```
Docs   amazing early flight flights got great prices
 1       1     0      1       0      0     0      0
 2       0     1      0       0      1     0      0
 3       0     0      0       1      0     1      1
```

How can this be done in Python?

Comment: You're asking ***"how do I create a predictive model from a DTM"*** which already has countless duplicates on this site and elsewhere in tutorials. Also, when you say 'predict', what exactly are you trying to predict? (topic (=>multiclass classification)? sentiment? the identity of the writer? the next sentence? etc. etc.) **You need to know which thing you're trying to predict, and your dataset needs to have labels.**

Comment: What I am asking is, how to create the same code that I have above in R into Python. The predictive part will come later, I first need to put my text data into a matrix form. I also searched this forum for "how do I create a predictive model from a DTM" and the only results that showed up were for R, not Python.

Comment: Ok then you're not asking how to create a predictive model, only **how to do text preprocessing then extract text features into a DTM**. Again, there are tons of tutorials out there you can easily find, both with [NLTK - Ch. 03 - Processing Raw Text](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html) and [spacy.io](https://spacy.io/), both of those tutorials show you. But asking for recommendations of tutorials is off-topic on SO. Unless you encounter a specific coding problem, in which case you can post your code and ask it here.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I took a look and did a keyword search. Nowhere does it even say the word "Matrix" let alone "Document Term Matrix". On top of that I actually own the physical copy of Python Text Processing with NLTK by Jacob Perkins, have read it and also cannot find what I am looking for there. So really I don't see how I have not done my due diligence to ensure that this topic has not been covered here or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The **DocumentTermMatrix** equivalent in Python is called **CountVectorizer**

```
text= ["amazing flight","got there early","great prices on flights??"]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd

vectorizer= CountVectorizer() 
X= vectorizer.fit_transform(text)
Y= vectorizer.get_feature_names()
final_output= pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(),columns=Y)
```

Which gives the following result:

```
       amazing  early  flight  flights  got  great  on  prices  there
0      1        0      1       0        0    0      0   0       0
1      0        1      0       0        1    0      0   0       1
2      0        0      0       1        0    1      1   1       0
```